# Why is the same html/css for my .subnav working on one page, but not another?

Tags: html, css, syntax, cross-browser

So I'm extremely new to this html and css thing and I've got a bit of a problem. I'm in the middle of cutting a site for the very first time, but I'm having issues with the positioning of my sub navigation.

My issue is that the Sub Nav on my FAQS Page is being pushed off center and towards the right in the browser. But then, the subnav on the other pages like 'support', which use exactly the same html structure and css style as the one on the FAQS page, are fine and perfectly centered.

When I 'inspect element' in the browser, it seems to be thinking there's an extra subnav button on the left hand side and  that the FAQS subnav button is positioned in the middle of the subnav , if that makes sense?

There's a second FAQS Page in the folder which works...but that was made by literally copy and pasting the code from the support page and then cutting out the bits that weren't needed, then copying in the parts from the FAQS page that I needed onto this .html instead.

So I have a feeling it's just a typo or a syntax error or something realllllly simple. I just really want to know what I did so I can avoid it in the future and know how to fix it.

**Here is the html for my sub nav ( & page title ):**

```
<div class="grid grid-pad">
            <div class="col-1-1">
                <div class="subnav clearfix">
                    <a href="support.html"class="b1"> Support </a>
                    <a href="FAQS.html"class="b1 subactive"> FAQS <div class="triangle"> </div> </a>
                    <a href="membersforum.html"class="b1"> Swifd Forum </a>
                    <a href="videotutorials.html"class="b1"> Video Tutorials </a>
            </div>
                <div class="pagetitle">
                    <h1 class="pageheading"> FAQS </h1>
                    <div class="pageheadingborder"> </div>
                    <h2 class="subtitleFAQS"> Got questions that need answering? <strong> we've got you covered</strong></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**And Here is the CSS so far:**

```
/*---------------- SUB NAV ---------------*/

.subnav {
    margin: 0 0 60px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.subnav a {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:'Bebas Neue', 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#000000;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin:5px;
    width: 180px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
}

a.b1.subactive {
    background-color: #ee812c;
}

a.b1.subactive div.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height:0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 32.5px 0 32.5px;
    border-color: #ee812c transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.subnav a:active {
    top: 2px;
}
```

I know it's a bit rusty, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an extremely basic model : https://jsfiddle.net/2Ly4v9qu/

Thankyou!

Comment: Could you supply a working demo of your issue? With the limited code you have posted, i canno't see the issue Nor replicate it in jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm not too sure If I've done this right...

https://jsfiddle.net/2Ly4v9qu/

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle, 
But, i'm affraid i still cannot see any issues with your "Sub-nav"/FAQ, the only parts i can see which is moving to the right(when zooming out) is the top login/navigation/ language selections & search bar.

Comment: It sounds really odd, I am unable to replicate your issue on Jsfiddle, so if it is possible for you to Either compress your files in a .zip (or w/e format) and upload them to a filehost for me, Or, upload your files to a free webhost(free account creations usually required) like 000webhost.com for testing purposes and pass the link here, then i'll be more than happy take a look at it either locally or online and see if i can replicate & track the issue.. But at this stage, there isn't anything else i can do.